# Changing what appears first in datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this column `dat`:

That looks like this:

```
           dat
0      2018-06-18
1      2018-06-24
2      2018-06-26
3      2018-06-27
4      2018-06-29
5      2018-12-07
6      2018-07-31
7      2018-01-08
8      2018-06-08
9      2018-07-08
10     2018-08-08
11     2018-08-27
12     2018-08-31
```

I want the date to look like `'%d/%m/%Y'`

```
b['dat']=pd.to_datetime(b['dat'],dayfirst= 1) #either this or 
b['dat']=pd.to_datetime(b['dat'],dayfirst= 0)
```

or even `yearfirst` =`True` or `False` looks the same and nothing changes.

I know I can do this:

`b['dat'] = b['dat'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` but it changes the datetime to object data type. While with the other approach doesn't.

Comment: It is impossible in python, because `datetime`s has always same structure `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: It is used if format of dates is like `05-04-2015`, then `dayfirst=True` is for correct parsing to `2015-04-05` - it is day 5, not day 4

Comment: So should I use `b['dat'] = b['dat'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') ` this even though it turns datetime to object? is it wrong if that happens?

Comment: Yes, you can change format, but lost datetimes. But if want datetimes in custom format, it is impossible in python.

Comment: does it have any negative effects if it become object?

Comment: sure, you cannot working with datetimes functions, best is working with datetimes and last step before writing to file is use `strftime`

Comment: nice. One more thing. if it is so what is the purpose of  the format parameter in `to.datetime` if it is not effective: `b['dt']=pd.to_datetime(b['dt'],format='%d%m%Y')`?

Comment: No, you are wrong. It is best define it, because then it is more effective - `to_datetime` not guess correct format of datetimes.

Comment: But it doesn't change it to format='%d%m%Y'. it remains the same in this case.

Comment: No, it is used if datetimes are like `05-04-2015`

Comment: `datetime` stores dates as integers. Any specific formatting you see is a *string representation*. See marked duplicate for a more complete explanation.